# Override customer method in magento issue?

Tags: overrides

So this is my modules/Namespace_Module.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This is the namespace/module/etc/config.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <namespace_module before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">Namespace_Module_Frontend_Customer</namespace_module >
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and this is the namespace/module/controllers/Frontend/Customer/AccountController.php content:

```
<?php 
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';
class Namespace_Module_Frontend_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        parent::indexAction();
    }
    public function editPostAction()
    {
        echo 1; exit();
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve when I update the my account inputs, when i click on the update button to show me the echo 1; exit(); At the moment nothing happens. What am I missing ? thx

Comment: You need to change `codepool` to `codePool` and `before="Mage_Customer_AccountController"` to `before="Mage_Customer"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your modules/Namespace_Module.xml file, try changing `<codepool>` to `<codePool>`.

Comment: good catch @user3661841

Answer (score 3):

Instead, you can try as:

change

```
<codepool>local</codepool>
```

to

```
 <codePool>local</codePool>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <namespace_module before="Mage_Customer">Namespace_Module</namespace_module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And create a controller class:
app/code/[codePool]/namespace/module/controllers/AccountController.php
with the following code

```
<?php 
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';
class Namespace_Module_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        parent::indexAction();
    }
    public function editPostAction()
    {
        echo 1; exit();
    }
}
```

check more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110042/cant-seem-to-override-checkout-controller-in-magento/7117076#7117076)

Comment: Thx for helping me , but I already tried this version and nothing changed :(

Comment: check xml file is correct and is loaded.make sure it should not include space in  line <args>
                    <modules>
                        <namespace_module before="Mage_Customer">Namespace_Module</namespace_module>
                    </modules>
                </args>

Comment: this is my xml <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <namespace_module before="Mage_Customer">Namespace_Module</namespace_module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>

Comment: I did not find any mistakes

Comment: check your log file at var/log/ is there any issue

Comment: nothing, no error no logs . I have absolutely no idea why it is not working

Comment: is there any other module installed which override customer controller ?

Comment: I don't believe so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32050/discussion-between-minesh-patel-and-chester).