# How to override the controller AccountController

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers, customer-account

I need to override a method Controller

```
Core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

and add a new method. Since this controller to edit is wrong - it should be overridden.

According to the project requirements override the controller must be at

```
local/New/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

To do this, create a file config, but addresses `customer/account/test`, `customer/account` `/ajax` did not respond, and `customer/account/login` It is not overridden. Please help in this implementation.

**app/app/etc/modules/New_Mage_Customer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
      <New_Mage_Customer>
           <active>true</active>
           <codePool>local</codePool>
      </New_Mage_Customer>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/New/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <New_Mage_Customer>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </New_Mage_Customer>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <new_customer before="Mage_Customer">New_Mage_Customer</new_customer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/New/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Customer account controller
 */
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';

class New_Mage_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController {

    public function ajaxAction() {
        echo 'ajax!!';
    }

    public function testAction() {
        echo 'test222';
    }

    public function loginAction() {
        echo 'index';
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: check here (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91413/override-customer-method-in-magento-issue/91419?noredirect=1#comment122065_91419)

Answer (score 22):

The file name will be **app/etc/modules/New_Mage.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
      <New_Mage>
           <active>true</active>
           <codePool>local</codePool>
      </New_Mage>
  </modules>
</config>
```

In **app/code/local/New/Mage/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <New_Mage>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </New_Mage>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <New_Mage before="Mage_Customer">New_Mage</New_Mage>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

controller will 
**app/code/local/New/Mage/controllers/AccountController.php**

```
/**
 * Customer account controller
 */
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer') . DS . 'AccountController.php';

class New_Mage_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController {

    public function ajaxAction() {
        echo 'ajax!!';
    }

    public function testAction() {
        echo 'test222';
    }

    public function loginAction() {
        echo 'index';
    }

}
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento/override-magento-controller/)

Comment: Will this not override all `customer` requests, including `example.com/customer/address/new/`? and if there is no address controller in this new module, all `/customer/address/*` requests will now 404