# How to add additional info to salesOrderEntity Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, model

this :

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
var_dump($order);
```

will return the details of an order by increment_id, however I only get customer_id, what to do in order to return for example the date of birth ? (without fetching information about the customer with the customer_id)

Answer (score 1):

it just go simple,Just

use **`$order->getCustomerDob();`**,

At **`customer_dob`** column at **sales_flat_order** table of db magento has save customer dob

Comment: sorry cannot get it to work...

Comment: hi amit, plaease look at here once http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133817/login-with-mobile-number

Answer (score 0):

**Remember guest orders are not associated with any customer.**

Hope this helps.

**Update [1]**

Even better way:

```
//get only guest orders
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(); 

//print all customer who made guest checkout
foreach($orders as $order){
   echo "<pre>".$order->getCustomerFirstname() ." ".$order->getCustomerLastname()." - ".$order->getCustomerEmail()."</pre>";
   //...........
   //there are lot of other customer attributes you can print.
}
```