# Shipping charge not transferring to PayPal Express from Shopping cart - magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, paypal-express

I have a site that I am building and whenever I press the **"checkout with paypal express" button(Shopping cart page)** ***the shipping rates aren't being processed on Paypal for guest customer***.

In Cart page, Shipping are calculated in summary block but when payment are paid through paypal express button, Paypal popup only show subtotal.

I get to the Paypal Login screen on popup when click on button, where it shows  the "Login" form and subtotal calculated.

Looking at the summary, the overall total doesn't add shipping - does anyone know how to fix this problem? Any help for issue.

**When i am logged in, Paypal is calculated shipping charge properly when I click from shopping cart page.**

Thanks.

Comment: Hi please have a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133817/login-with-mobile-number-without-extension

Comment: does you know about payeezy payment gateway

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya , have you found solution for this ?

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya , Any solution for this issues ?

Comment: @Impunkj, Not find any solutions

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, Thanks for reply  i think this is default functionality. Okay lets look up

Answer (score 2):

**In your admin panel, go to:**

Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Paypal Express Checkout > Configure > Advanced Settings > Transfer Shipping Options > Set this options to **Yes**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have already set yes in paypal configuration.

Comment: Have you enabled debug mode for Paypal? 
What can you see in your log? 
Can you show your log please?

Comment: for guest customer paypal not show shipping charge for logged in customer its display final total so how to display for guest customer to final total in paypal popup?

Comment: Can you please specify your Magento 2 version please? Have you tried this with last Magento CE 2.1.4?

Comment: magento version is 2.1.3

Comment: Can you please show your debug.log regarding Paypal?

Answer (score 0):

@Rakesh Jesadiya have you found solution for this?