# Magebuzz manufacturers extension on a static block

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, cms-block, manufacturer

I'm tring to display the manufacturer list in a Static Block on Magento 1.9.3.2

But cannot understand how to do this:

```
{{block type="Magebuzz/Manufacturer" name="manufacturer" template="Product/manufacturer.phtml"}}
```

Where can I find "**type**" and "**template**" in the extension file and folder to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue with block white listing, for that

Please go to

`System->permission->blocks`

and click on `addnewblock`  add your block `Magebuzz/Manufacturer` and set `enable` in dropdown and then click on `save`.

clear your cache and try again

Comment: Thank you Murtuza, but it doesn't work. using {{block type="core/template" name="manufacturer" template="manufacturer/manufacturer.phtml"}} works, but now I've not result from manufacturer extension. Thank you

Comment: @Aculine please provide me link of that extension

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala this is the module:  https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shop-by-manufacturer-2.html

Comment: @Aculine let me check that extension I will let you know

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, Hi please have alook at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133817/login-with-mobile-number-without-extension